# What IE DOM activities slow down a page with massive links?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, dom, hyperlink, visited

IE pages with huge numbers of links (> 5000) seem to exhibit slow response clicking on a link.  If it is relevant, most (98%) of these links are in-page links (`#`).

The typical behavior I see is that when you lick a link, a 1-3 sec delay occurs before moving to the href target.

In one section of the site that contains these pages, I see a script console error when clicking on a link:  something to the effect that different CSS cannot be applied to `:visited` and that only color changes would be applied.  This suggests to me that the issue happens by how IE handles the page DOM when applying color changes to a given link (now that it is `:visited`).

From this I assume that IE has a poor mechanism for indexing pages with a huge number of links.

**Is there a way around this?*

Comment: Don't [crosspost](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51029/what-ie-dom-activities-slow-down-a-page-with-massive-links?noredirect=1) across [multiple](http://superuser.com/questions/623171/what-ie-dom-activities-slow-down-a-page-with-massive-links?noredirect=1) sites on [se]

Comment: I've never posted on an IE-related tag before, and was unsure if it was mostly-inactive on any one of the sites.  Seeing the migrations of the other questions, I've with draw my question on the others.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? How does the page perform if you *don't* have any CSS in the page at all?

Comment: IE 7, 8 & 9 all exhibit the problem.  I haven't yet tried to turn off CSS rendering to see the different;  good thought.